# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException Google Ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.native_invoke(MediaPlayer.java)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.invoke(MediaPlayer.java:792)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.getInbandTrackInfo(MediaPlayer.java:2955)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.getTrackInfo(MediaPlayer.java:2931)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.video.b.run(b.java:3)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
   at qm.a(qm.java)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.f.a(f.java:1)
   at qm.dispatchMessage(qm.java)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I have been using the google android ad sdk for more than one year and from last two weeks this crash popped up from all the versions of my app and before that there were no crashes. Crash count is increasing. Does anyone facing the same issue with google ads?

Dependency : ->
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm facing the same error with 19.4.0 version

Comment: @RosarioVivas No . I didn't . Even I upgraded sdk version with 19.6.0.